# How to store an unique Blazor sessionID for each client?

Tags: blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-webassembly

We are using a shared Razor Class Library for our Blazor applications containing all components, that both our Blazor Server and Blazor WebAssembly startup projects are using.

However, when we open another tab or browser window, going to the same URL, we noticed that the session persists.

We tried creating an unique guid in JavaScript, and invoking it to the app using **IJSRuntime**. That unique guid is then used inside all components to show the correct data loaded from our API. It doesn't always work however, and it is not good perfomance wise either.

Because we are using a shared Razor Class Library, we are not able to use the **ProtectedSessionStorage**. How can we get unique sessions without using JavaScript interop calls?

Comment: What do you mean precisely by "session"? How do you "notice the session persists"?

Comment: With "session", I mean an unique connection to the app using SignalR. So opening the same URL in another tab should be unique in our case.

Currently, when we click on a button on the second tab, the first tab also got updated.

Comment: @Dagovax, reading your Q and comment, I guess do you have issues with DI scoped. For example, if you run the default counter template in two tabs, when you click in one tab, the other one doesn't increase the counter.

Comment: Exactly, @daniherrera - we would need to know more about the precise nature of what is updating on both tabs - and dig into how that feature has been implemented. The OP should provide relevant code - ideally with repro we can inspect.

Comment: "Sessions" i.e. services scoped as `Scoped` or `Transient` are unique to each "session".  They don't persist.  Only Singletons persist across sessions.  What data is persisting and where is it stored?  Are you using DI?  Put up some code.  At the moment there's no answer to your question.

Answer (score 3):

To give each Window/BrowserTab-Session a unique-Id just add a scoped service in Program.cs. If this is what your want.

[image]

Each instance of the App gets a unique Id that can be passed on to your library-components, in order to identify a tab/window instance as long as this session lastes.

Code for Blazor Webassably

Add in Program.cs

```
     builder.Services.AddScoped<MyIdService>();
```

Add the MyIdService.cs class

```
    public class MyIdService
    {
        public Guid MyGuid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
```

Add/inject this to every page you need this behavior. Or to make it more simple just add it to the shared/mainlayout.razor file.

```html
    @inherits LayoutComponentBase
    @inject MyIdService MyIdService
    
    <div class="page">
        <div class="sidebar">
            <NavMenu />
        </div>
    
        <main>
            <div class="top-row px-4">
                <h4>@MyIdService.MyGuid</h4>
            </div>
    
            <article class="content px-4">
                @Body
            </article>
        </main>
    </div>
```

The Id is only good as long as a user session lasts. If you want to store state of every user for later use. You would need a userlogin and some sort of datapersisting.